# MATE Indicator Applet Complete No Indicators failure

Tags: indicator, mate

I fully understand that this general list is not the MATE list.  However, I am NOT running MATE Ubuntu, I am running stock Ubuntu 22.04 LTS current using a MATE desktop GUI.  I have done this in 18.04LTS and everything "worked", upgraded in place (NOT A FRESH INSTALL) to 20.04LTS, and then upgraded in place to 22.04LTS -- everything worked.  However, the 2TB spinning hard drive was too slow and I needed more storage capacity, so I installed a 4TB SSD, did a fresh install of 22.04LTS from the Ubuntu stock 22.04 current bootable .iso image that I used to create a bootable USB install drive, and the restored my previous personal drives, such as /home from the working 22.04 2TB system (not a different Ubuntu LTS release than what I was using).  The MATE Indicator Applet Complete worked before, but now fails with No Indicators.  I am aware of the MATE Ubuntu forum question on this topic (the URL below); however, this does not address my issue.  I do *NOT* want to run a base OS other than Canonical Ubuntu LTS current.  Both the 2TB system and the current 4TB system are "up to date".

[MATE indicator applet from the MATE Ubuntu list](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mate-indicator-applet/25125)

Something clearly is missing, most likely a MATE or other package.  Any assistance greatly would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have the Ayatana Indicators installed?

Comment: gir1.2-ayatanaido3-0.4 is already the newest version (0.9.1-1)

Comment: Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 ayatana-indicator-common all 0.9.7-1 [14.6 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 ayatana-indicator-application amd64 22.2.0-1 [29.0 kB]

Comment: The above eliminates the "no indicators" message.  The package should be automatically installed by the MATE installation -- I had to search on the web to find the above package.

Comment: Please EDIT the question and make it readable. Also do not put additional info for the question as comments again EDIT the question and add the info. The comments are where we ask you for more info so help can be offered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from "Esther" above -- actually a question -- allowed me to solve the No Indicators issue from the MATE panel applet.  I had to do a web search to find the correct package name and then `apt install` of the correct name worked.

Get:1 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 ayatana-indicator-common all 0.9.7-1 [14.6 kB]
Get:2 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 ayatana-indicator-application amd64 22.2.0-1 [29.0 kB] –

The above eliminates the "no indicators" message. The package/s should be automatically installed by the MATE "desktop" installation under 22.04LTS but evidently is not.